# How to apply css background color to text only, in datatables cell

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'd like to apply background color css to text in a datatable cell. Currenytly I can only apply the color to the whole cell, how can I apply it only to the text in the cell?
Here is what I am using now:

```
$.each(aData, function(ii,value2){
          if (value.sTitle == "Priority" && aData[i] != ""){
              $('td:eq(' + i + ')', nRow).css('background-color', '#F6CED8');
            }   
        });
```

Comment: Are you talking about background color for the text or the color for the text itself? If you need to have a background color for the text, you need to put it in another container - div or p. If you want the text to be of a certain color - it's color, not the background-color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other user said. Put it inside div or p tags and change the background color of that specific object.

Comment: I should clarify. what I mean is I want to change the background color of the area covered by text only, not the empty space in the cell.